# nxlog.conf filtering windows event log issues

Tags: windows, logging, event-log, graylog, nxlog

I'm trying to pull specific windows event logs using nxlog and displaying them in graylog. It is retrieving the logs just fine, however, my problem is that:
Even with a query, it still seems to pull a lot of data that is not specified in the query (e.g. here I specify Application with specific eventID's that I have been testing by creating dummy logs in cmd).

For example, I am still getting System, Security and various other logs appearing in graylog.

I'm very new to this so I'm probably missing something stupid. Here's a snip from my .conf:

[nxlog.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnsRZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to test the XML query in event viewer. It's exactly the same there which you can copy-paste into your nxlog.conf.

If you are not getting filtered events it's either because you did not restart NXLog or still old events are showing up in Graylog.

Comment: how do you test the XML query in event viewer?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askds/advanced-xml-filtering-in-the-windows-event-viewer